# Javascript parse object key value from string keys

Tags: javascript

I have custom object

```
var user = {
  name: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  details: {
    age: 33,
    gender: "male",
    education: {
      university: "Oxford"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I need to function which can parse object key from string. E.g function args:

```
getObjectKeyValue("details.age") // 33
getObjectKeyValue("details.education.university") // Oxford
```

How can be realised like this function to get object key value from string dots based key?

Comment: Why not directly accessing the object (e.g., `user.details.age`)?

Comment: This objects passed on translation file and translation strings has dynamic params which must be defined on function arguments. E.g translation string `Welcome ${username} to our website` @Arik

Comment: You can use "optional chaining" like so: eval("user?." + "details.education.university".replace(/\./g, '?.'))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be better solution but you can try this

```js
var user = {
  name: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  details: {
    age: 33,
    gender: "male",
    education: {
      university: "Oxford"
    }
  }
}

console.log(getObjectKeyValue("details.age"))
console.log(getObjectKeyValue("details.education.university"))

function getObjectKeyValue(param){
 var params=param.split(".");
 var obj=user
 params.forEach(el=>{
    obj=obj[el]
 })
 return obj;
}
```